# Firebase (FCM) grouped notification click from same App

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented FCM and push notification receiving successfully in App. And also it opens the specific activity when I clicked the notification. If more than one notifications received, the notifications are collapsed in status bar. When I click the grouped notification, it will simply opens the App. It is working fine with expanded view. Can I able to trigger any event when App opens from grouped FCM push notification??

Comment: I think this is the default behaviour when a user clicks on the group of notification it will open up the application itself. You can apply different group ID if you don't want the notification to group up.

Comment: @RudrikPatel: Is any possibility to add listener event when clicks the grouped notification?

Comment: I think not. We are just adding a pending intent while creating a notification and the Android system does the rest of the work.